# How to design Multi qubit Controlled Z rotations

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate

I need some help in multi-qubit controlled -Z rotation.
Below is the qiskit code of triple controlled z rotation

```
def cccZ():                                      
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.cp(pi/4, 0, 3)            

qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cp(-pi/4, 1, 3)

qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cp(pi/4, 1, 3)

qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.cp(-pi/4, 2, 3)

qc.cx(0, 2)
qc.cp(pi/4, 2, 3)

qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.cp(-pi/4, 2, 3)

qc.cx(0, 2)
qc.cp(pi/4, 2, 3)


gate = qc.to_gate(label=' cccZ')
return gate
```

Please help me in modifying this code to hexa qubit z rotation? It would be really great if someone can explain its theory also. I am really struggling with random nature of quantum computing with no fixed pattern at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mostly flexible way to create gates beyond the ones included as methods is with the circuit library:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate

circuit = QuantumCircuit(7)
c6z = ZGate().control(6)
circuit.append(c6z, range(7))
circuit.draw()
```

```
q_0: ─■─
      │ 
q_1: ─■─
      │ 
q_2: ─■─
      │ 
q_3: ─■─
      │ 
q_4: ─■─
      │ 
q_5: ─■─
      │ 
q_6: ─■─
```

The decomposition of this gate is deep:

```
circuit.decompose().depth()
```

```
315
```

#### How to construct multi-controlled gates, in general

Any single-qubit gate can be arbitrarily-n-controlled with [the method `Gate.control`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.html?#qiskit.circuit.Gate.control). The parameter `n` sets the amount of controlled qubits. As a consequence, the resulting controlled-gate will be a n-plus-one-qubits gate.

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import <some>Gate
cN_gate = <some>Gate(<gate_params>).control(<n>)
print(cN_gate.num_qubits)  # n+1
```

You can append this custom gate to a circuit using [the `QuantumCircuit.append` method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.append):

```
circuit.append(cN_gate, [....., i])
                         \_n_/
```

The first $n$ parameters are the qubits in which you want to control. The last one (`i`) is the target qubit.

Comment: Thank you @Luciano. Please provide some methodology or trick to understand these quantum gates and circuit?

Comment: I generalized it, have a look

Comment: Thank you @Luciano